# change label from left to right to right to left in pie graph in highchart

Tags: javascript, jquery, graph, highcharts, pie-chart

http://jsfiddle.net/tfpmuwd9/

```
if (degree >= 90 && degree <= 270) {
                    rotation = degree - 180;
                    point.dataLabel.x = 0;
                    point.dataLabel.y = 0;
                    point.dataLabel.translateX = (point.labelPos[2] + point.labelPos[4]) / 2;
                    point.dataLabel.translateY = (point.labelPos[3] + point.labelPos[5]) / 2;
                } else {
                    point.dataLabel.x = 0;
                    point.dataLabel.y = 0;
                    rotation = degree - 180;
                    point.dataLabel.translateX = (point.labelPos[2] + point.labelPos[4]) / 2;
                    point.dataLabel.translateY = (point.labelPos[3] + point.labelPos[5]) / 2;
                }

                point.dataLabel.rotation = Math.floor(rotation);
                point.dataLabel.show();
                point.dataLabel.updateTransform();

                });
                }
                }
        },
```

above link is pie chart.i want to change the direction of write of label of it ... there is write issues 4,3,2,1 from project 5,4,3 is good to readable format , now from project 1,2... i want to write is read good from which is that is left to right now i want it from right to left .. some half is good but another half is not proper ...

http://jsfiddle.net/tfpmuwd9/5/

```
if (degree >= 90 && degree <= 270) {
                    rotation = degree - 180;
                    point.dataLabel.x = 0;
                    point.dataLabel.y = 0;
                    point.dataLabel.translateX = (point.labelPos[2] + point.labelPos[4]) / 2;
                    point.dataLabel.translateY = (point.labelPos[3] + point.labelPos[5]) / 2;
                } else {
                    point.dataLabel.x = 0;
                    point.dataLabel.y = 0;
                    rotation = degree;
                    point.dataLabel.translateX = (point.labelPos[2] + point.labelPos[4]) / 2;
                    point.dataLabel.translateY = (point.labelPos[3] + point.labelPos[5]) / 2;
                }

                point.dataLabel.rotation = Math.floor(rotation);
                point.dataLabel.show();
                point.dataLabel.updateTransform();

                });
                }
                }
        },
```

i need around of this .. but in proper position what should i do ??

Comment: Are you looking for RTL text direction (Arabic and Hebrew)? *{direction:rtl;}

Comment: Noo.. i am managing the position of it ..you can see in second link .. that i have change but it gone out of chart .. i need it inside it

Comment: This is the closest I could get: http://jsfiddle.net/tfpmuwd9/7/

Comment: I would set `text-anchor` for right labels, see: http://jsfiddle.net/tfpmuwd9/8/ Or manipulate dataLabel position a bit more using `translateX` and `translateY`, as you already did.

Comment: Thank you @RaeenHashemi
Dear Raeen any other property that we can set in exact middle.. you are very close to it so ...

Comment: Thank you @PawełFus
should i apply to any other property for exact one ... and css property ..

Comment: @MILIND The exact middle of the slice is **`point.labelPos[2]`** and **`point.labelPos[3]`** for the left half. But for the right, I used the average of 4 and 5 with **`point.shapeArgs`** which is the center for that slice. I couldn't make it exactly as the left side because of the lack of wanted values.

Comment: By including Pawel's method, I came to this: http://jsfiddle.net/tfpmuwd9/9/

Comment: After including some math, you can achieve this: http://jsfiddle.net/tfpmuwd9/10/

Comment: Thank  you @RaeenHashemi
i ll try my self and will post it .. :) Thank you so much

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/tfpmuwd9/13/

hey see, getting more problem when name is more .. see on right side project one is issue-1 is good to start ... but it going to problem when name is long and same as on left side .. i can't find same as corner .. i think now you get all the issues @RaeenHashemi

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/05xp3tdf/4/ 

i think now its too small changes require .. can any css or any more logic apply that can get out put .. @PawełFus and also check Raeen

Comment: I'm sorry, I think I'm missing your question? You want to change size of the pie? Set different width/height for the container.

Comment: if label is more long then it ll not add to in before given link so i change the size of container and try to now for the label should be in pie chart like "Project-1 issue 2 " so i need it in pie chart